# Updating a property used in dict in a class

Tags: python, dictionary, properties

I am trying to achieve to dynamically update some parameters in object.
Let's have a property that I use in some dict ->

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = None
        self.some_dict = {"id": self.id}

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, new_id: int):
        self._id = new_id

tst = Test()
tst.id = 112
print(tst.id) # 112
print(tst.some_dict) # {'id': None}
```

The desired result is to have:

```
print(tst.some_dict) # {'id': 112}
```

How to update the dictionary after some parameter (`id`) as a property will be updated?

**Edit:**
Sure thing I can do:

```
@id.setter
def id(self, new_id: int):
    self._id = new_id
    self._some_dict.update({"id": self._id})
```

But for a lot of parameters it is kind of exhausting to write, is there any automatic way?

Comment: The dict won't implicitly update because some other variable updates. You either need to explicitly update the dict in the setter, or you make `some_dict` a `@property` as well and always create it on-the-fly.

Comment: "is there any automatic way?" Well, you can create the dict automatically when the user asks for it. You already know the tool to use for this - it's the same one you're using now to create the id value automatically when the user asks for it.

Comment: there is no `self._some_dict` in your code. (typo?) You are using getters and setters without _doing_ anything special in them, simply use `self.id` instead - unless you really need a getter/setter for logic . python works just fine without it - and it is simpler/easier to understand

Comment: you could always forgoe the `self._id = None` in your class and instead pull/put  all your values (via getter/setter) from the dict that you use as "generic" backingfield - but that makes not much sense as the class already has a dict that stores all its members ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the `__dict__` attribute of your instance and return a sanitized version of this `dict`.

Example: (should work as is)

```
class A:
    _prohibited_keys = ["instance", "variables", "you", "dont", "want", "to", "show"]

    def __init__(self):
        self._id = None
    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, value: int):
        self._id = value

    @property
    def dict(self):
        return {self._private_to_pub_key(k): v for k, v in self.__dict__.items()
                if k not in self._prohibited_keys and not k.startswith('__')}

    def _private_to_pub_key(self, k):
        return k[1:] if k.startswith('_') else k




a = A()
print(a.dict)
>>> {'id': None}
```

Comment: no need for getters/setters at all if there is no logic inside the functions but beside the point - minor nitpick: if you happen to create own dunder methods in your  class, your `private_to_pub_key` will remove one of the leading 2 underscores.

Comment: I actually use this method in my code: `return sanitize(k): v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if k not in self._prohibited_keys and not k.startswith('__')`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add line `self.some_dict['id'] = new_id` to the `def id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = None
        self.some_dict = {"id": self.id}
    
    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id
    
    @id.setter
    def id(self, new_id: int):
        self._id = new_id
        self.some_dict['id'] = new_id



tst = Test()
tst.id = 112
print(tst.id) # 112
print(tst.some_dict) # {'id': 112}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can update it inside `id.setter` function:

```
    @id.setter
    def id(self, new_id: int):
        self._id = new_id
        self.some_dict.update({'id': new_id})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to automate things to some degree, as in the sense of eliminating a lot of repetitive coding. In the code below this is being done by utilizing a combination of a utility function that creates the properties along with a metaclass that post-processes the class definition and to initialize the dictionary you also want it to also have.

The latter involves searching for those that were defined and initializing both the instance storage attribute associated with their property name as well as the corresponding item in this additional dictionary. This requirement is what is making the creation of a class instance as complicated as it is, especially the need to have a metaclass — so you might want to reconsider whether that's really necessary or not.

```
def dict_property(name):
    """ Define property with given name that updates a private attribute and the
        instance's dictionary named some_dict.
    """
    storage_name = '_' + name

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return getattr(self, storage_name)

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        setattr(self, storage_name, value)
        self.some_dict.update({name: value})

    return prop


class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict, **kwargs):
        """ Initialize dict_property values in class and some_dict to None. """

        names = []
        for name, value in classdict.items():
            if isinstance(value, property):
                #print(f'found property named {name!r}')
                names.append(name)

        some_dict = {}
        for name in names:
            storage_name = '_' + name
            classdict[storage_name] = None
            some_dict[name] = None

        classdict['some_dict'] = some_dict  # Add dict to class.

        # Create the class.
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict, **kwargs)


class Test(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    id = dict_property('id')
    age = dict_property('age')


tst = Test()
print(f'{tst.id=}')         # -> tst.id=None
print(f'{tst.age=}')        # -> tst.age=None
print(f'{tst.some_dict=}')  # -> tst.some_dict={'id': None, 'age': None}
print()
tst.id = 112
print(f'{tst.id=}')         # -> tst.id=112
print(f'{tst.age=}')        # -> tst.age=None
print(f'{tst.some_dict=}')  # -> tst.some_dict={'id': 112, 'age': None}
print()
tst.age = 42
print(f'{tst.id=}')         # -> tst.id=112
print(f'{tst.age=}')        # -> tst.age=42
print(f'{tst.some_dict=}')  # -> tst.some_dict={'id': 112, 'age': 42}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `@property` decorator with `some_dict`:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = None

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, new_id: int):
        self._id = new_id

    @property
    def some_dict(self):
        return {'id': self.id}

tst = Test()
tst.id = 112
print(tst.id) # 112
print(tst.some_dict) # {'id': 112}
```